# How to render default Magento registration form in popup?

Tags: magento2, template, forms, modal-popup, customer-registration

I have a button "Registration for dealer" on customer/account/create/ page that outputs a popup. My goal is to render in the popup the default customer registration form that's fully functional.
Popup modal is created with RequireJS and works as intended.
Form's location is \vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\templates\form\register.phtml

The layout is at vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\layout\customer_account_create.xml

This is the content of my customer_account_create.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceBlock name="form.additional.info">
                <block class="Alex\Lesson5Homework\Block\CustomBlock" name="custom.registration.block" as="custom_registration_block" template="Alex_Lesson5Homework::dealer_registration.phtml" />
            </referenceBlock>
        </body>
    </page>
```

This is PHP block that returns a simple string for now:

```
class CustomBlock extends Template
{
    public function getContent()
    {
        return 'Dummy Content';
    }
}
```

I use getContent in my phtml template

```
<div id="modal-content">
    <?php echo $this->getContent(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Create popup in Magento : https://www.integerbyteblog.in/magento/how-to-show-cookie-popup-in-magento-2/

Comment: I have a popup already...

Comment: Well, I've been told my approach won't work.
How do I copy it from Magento properly then? What should I change in the native code to make it work in the popup?

Answer (score 0):

> I use getContent in my phtml template

Try once this code :-

```
<div id="modal-content">
    <?php echo $this->getContent(); ?>

    <?php 
echo this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register")->setTemplate("Magento_Customer::form/register.phtml")->toHtml();
 ?>
```

Comment: I tried this approach already. When I go to the page I see raw HTML only with error stack trace. The only solution is to completely copy-paste the existing form into my popup. That's the issue.